# understanding typedefs inside templates

Tags: c++, templates

I am  examining a sample code, which tries to teach state-charts implementation . I see typedefs in template such as `typedef typename T::HostClass Host`

For clarity, the template definition is

```
template<typename T>
struct Init {
    typedef typename T::HostClass Host;
    Init(Host& h) :
            host_(h) {
    }
    ~Init() {
        T::entry(host_);
        T::init(host_);
    }
    Host& host_;
};
```

I came to know the purpose of `typename` next to `typedef`, and is explaining `Highly-Typed-Languages` such as `C++`(Folks, Am i right ? Is it so?)

The confusion is at `HostClass`

In `typedef typename T::HostClass Host;`

- What is `HostClass`?
- Does it mean any type T must have a member
  `HostClass`?

Comment: The tut is from this page. `http://accu.org/index.php/journals/252`

Answer (score 3):

`HostClass` has to be a nested class or another typedef (or alias type) in the scope of `T`.

And if `T` doesn't have it, the code won't compile.

Comment: In and around the code, I don't see any typedef or alias for HostClass. And, it's not an nested class too,

Comment: @nmxprime its probably just a typo and should read `typedef T::Host Host`

Comment: I thinks it's not a type. The code compiles very well

Comment: @dwcanillas May it could be a typo, but how it's compiling then?

Comment: @nmxprime Where can you download this code? I don't see a link on the page.  If you are talking about the code in your post, chances are you didn't make an instance of the template, so the code was never actually compiled.

Comment: @dwcanillas, Yeah you are right! when i tried creating instances, it popped up. Thank you...